# i am not getting the required output in python

Tags: python, button, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('printer')
label = Label(root, text = "WELCOME", fg = "grey")

label.pack()
textbox = Entry(root)
textbox.pack()


def whenclicked():
    global hello
    hello = "textbox.get()"
    label1 = Label(root, text = hello)
    label1.pack()



button = Button(root, text = "print it", command = whenclicked())
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

when I run this code , before I click the button the output is already present . what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

All arguments of a function are evaluated before the function call, so when you call:

```
Button(root, text = "print it", command=whenclicked())
```

it first calls `whenclicked()` and then passes its result to the `Button` constructor. The `command` argument should be a function, so pass it just like that:

```
Button(root, text = "print it", command=whenclicked)
```

(Unrelated, but quotes in `hello = "textbox.get()"` are redundant, if you want to get the textbox content.)

Answer (score -2):

it looks like label might be part of mainloop which could cause it to function apart from the rest of your code without interaction take it out of mainloop.

Comment: still it is not working . can you give a little more clarification

Comment: It looks like your trying to run it before its declared in the code if its in mainloop its always going to be running like a light switch without an on off!